# How to set text color for TextView from theme variable in XML layout?

Tags: android

If I set color easy way, like this `android:textColor=?myThemeVariable`, then I getting iflating error.
How to resolve that trouble?

Comment: @DhruvSakariya This way is not suitable.
res-values-colors already has colors
<color name="md_theme_light_text_color">#000000</color>
<color name="md_theme_dark_text_color">#ffffff</color>
I need to use the variable that is defined for dark and light in themes.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are looking for is that your `TextView` or whatever view to be aligned with your configuration of *dark-mode* and *light-mode*, right?

So you'd need to have two `style.xml` files.

1. res/drawable/values/themes.xml
2. res/drawable/values/themes.xml(night)

Inside of each one you need to assign the color as follows :

`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>` (night)

`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>` (light)

So whenever you want to follow that rule in your `TextView` you can use `?android:textColorPrimary` as follows :

```
android:textColor = "?android:textColorPrimary"
```

Another option is instead of using `themes` you can create two `colors.xml`

1. values/colors.xml
2. values-night/colors.xml

Then there you have the color with the same name but changing the hex, so instead of having what you have

```
<color name="md_theme_light_text_color">#000000</color>
<color name="md_theme_dark_text_color">#ffffff</color>
```

On each `colors.xml` use :

```
<color name="textColor">#000000</color> //values/colors.xml
<color name="textColor">#ffffff</color> //values-nigh/colors.xml
```

So in your xml you can use `textColor` as follows :

```
android:textColor = "@color/textColor"
```

Comment: I was editing my answer, check again and check if it works please

Comment: Thank you so much, for some reason variant with themes not works, but variant with two colors.xml works for my case. Thanks)